# In ansible using the value of a previously assigned set_fact in a when conditional for jira task skips even though condition is met

Tags: ansible, jira

In my ansible playbook, I am trying to close jira tickets based on the condition - if the value of my set_fact is == 0, loop through the list of Jira ticket keys and close them all. The task is running on my defined host in my inventory (not localhost).

Here is my playbook:

```
# Get the length of x
  - name: Find the length of x
    set_fact:
      length_of_x: "{{ x | length }}"

  - name: Printing the length of x
    debug:
      var: length_of_x

# If x is an empty list, move JIRA tickets to "Closed" status and skip next steps
  - name: Close JIRA ticket
    jira:
      uri: 'https://ip.ip.ip.ip'
      username: 'foo'
      password: 'foo'
      validate_certs: false
      project: test
      issue: "{{ item.ticket_key }}"
      operation: transition
      status: Closed
    loop: "{{ ticket_key }}"
    when: **length_of_x == 0**    
    run_once: true
    register: jira_close_results

  - name: Print the complete response
    debug: var=jira_close_results
```

I am expecting that since I have x as an empty list, length_of_x == 0, thus the jira ticket will be closed. Instead I get this:

```
TASK [Printing x] ******************************************
ok: [host] => {
    "x": []
}

TASK [Find the length of x] **********************************
ok: [host]

TASK [Printing the length of x] **********************************
ok: [host] => {
    **"length_of_x": "0"**
}

TASK [Close JIRA ticket] *****************************
skipping: [host] => (item=test-100) 

TASK [Print the complete response] *********************************************
ok: [host] => {
    "jira_close_results": {
        "changed": false, 
        "msg": "All items completed", 
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
                "changed": false, 
                "item": "test-100", 
                "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False", 
                "skipped": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried many different ways of defining the when condition but nothing is working, it skips every time. Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,
Change the when statement to following,

```
when: length_of_x: "0" # To consider 0 as a string
or
when: length_of_x|int: 0 # To parse length_of_x as integer
```

Reason, Ansible returns a string for set_fact

[Reference](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/5463)